# NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector for Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using a Java Spark project and I wrote my HelloWorldSpark project as below. It's a maven build project.

```
[import spark.Spark;
import spark.Route;
import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;
public class HelloWrldSpark {
    public static void main(String\[\] args) {
        Spark.get(new Route("/"){
            @Override
            public Object handle(final Request request, final Response response){
                return "Hellow from Spark";
            }
        });
    }
}][1]
```

But when I tried to run the class, I am getting error as NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector . I opened the class called SparkServerImpl.java and found that the import statement import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;  is throwing error. Not sure what is going wrong, can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Try adding the JAR with that class to your runtime CLASSPATH in your Maven pom.xml

Comment: I have imported the jar file and after importing the jar file most of the error got away but 2. Now I am getting error at the below line :  connector.setIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1));     The error says that can't resolve the method setIdleTimeOut.                                          These are supposed to be class file defined by Spark Framework and these are not in editable mode, so not sure why I am getting error in these files.